# How to ensure tasks are executed simultaneously?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, testing, synchronization

I was implementing some multithreading unit-tests and came up with a problem that it is hard to ensure two jobs are actually executed in parallel - one always starts earlier then the other. Let's consider my initial implementation of test scenario to demonstrate the behavior:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var repeats = 1000000;
    var firstWinCount = 0;
    var secondWinCount = 0;
    int x = 0;

    long time1 = 0;
    long time2 = 0;

    long totalTimeDiff = 0;

    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++)
    {
        x = 0;
        var task1 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref x, 1, 0);
            time1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        });
        var task2 = new Task(() =>
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref x, 2, 0);
            time2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        });
        task1.Start();
        task2.Start();
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);

        totalTimeDiff += Math.Abs(time1 - time2);

        if (x == 1)
        {
            firstWinCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (x == 2)
            {
                secondWinCount++;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("First  win count: {0}, percentage: {1}", firstWinCount, firstWinCount / (double)repeats * 100);
    Console.WriteLine("Second win count: {0}, percentage: {1}", secondWinCount, secondWinCount / (double)repeats * 100);

    Console.WriteLine("Avg sync diff: {0}ns", totalTimeDiff * 1000000 / repeats);
}
```

The output is:

```
First  win count: 950538, percentage: 95,0538
Second win count: 49462, percentage: 4,9462
Avg sync diff: 1012ns
```

As we can see, most of the time first task starts executing earlier then second because it gets into thread pool first:

```
task1.Start();
task2.Start();
```

Since ThreadPool is quite unpredictable in a way tasks are scheduled, **there is absolutely no guarantee that first task will not complete until second task starts**. So it is hard to ensure we are actually testing multithreading scenario.

Surprisingly I couldn't find similar questions on the internet.

My own considerations and ideas with AutoResetEvents, locks and Interlock synchronization constructions led to the following solution of task synchronization:

```
int sync = 0;
var task1 = new Task(() =>
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref sync);
    while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sync, 3, 2) != 2) ;

    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref x, 1, 0);
    time1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
});
var task2 = new Task(() =>
{
    while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sync, 2, 1) != 1) ;

    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref x, 2, 0);
    time2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
});
```

Basically this idea ensures that both threads aren't blocked (so are likely having processor time) while waiting for other task to start processing. As a result I managed to reduce synchronization time difference from ~1000 nanoseconds to ~130 nanoseconds and greatly increase the probability of short-running tasks to be executed in parallel:

```
First  win count: 23182, percentage: 2,3182
Second win count: 976818, percentage: 97,6818
Avg sync diff: 128ns
```

Remaining downside is that ordering of tasks is still quite well-defined: first task always waits for second to complete, and second, once knows first is waiting for it, doesn't wait anymore and starts executing it's job. So second job is likely to start first. Exclusins (2.3%) are possible due to [relatively rare] thread switching as far as I understand. I can workaround it with randomizing sync order, but it's another complication.

**I wonder whether I'm reinventing the wheel and if there is better way to maximize the probability of two tasks to be executed simultaneously and with even probability of each starting slightly earlier.**

*PS:* I understand that multithreading scenarios usually are far slower then 100 nanoseconds (any thread switch or block on sync construction is at least 1000 times slower), so this delay in synchronization isn't that important in most cases. But it might be critical in testing non-blocking high-performance code.

Comment: There's *nothing* you can do to ensure they run at the same time.  The computer might not even have multiple CPUs, and so isn't *capable* of running two threads at once, or there might be other programs taking up so much of the CPU resources that you're only ever able to run one at once, or the OS could just *decide* to never schedule more than one thread for you app, because it's free to schedule threads however it wants.

Comment: So your are testing the .NET Task implementation? I think some guys at MS have already done this kind of test and you can be sure that 2 tasks are running in parallel (or at least in an old fashioned round-robin way).

Comment: @fharreau The tasks are *able* to run in parallel.  It's easy enough to do that.  *Requiring* them to run in parallel is going to be *impossible*, because it's dependant on the OS and the hardware, and most PCs these days don't have the framework in place to *require* something like that.

Comment: @Servy, taking into account it only makes sense in unit-tests scenario, we can more or less be sure we have multicore processor and it is free for our needs. It just increases the probability of running in parallel. The problem is that there is no processor-level non-blocking analogue of ManualResetEvent as I see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems there is no better solution then my idea with interlock synchronization, so I implemented it as reusable class and added randomization of starting order to ensure equal chance of starting order:

```
public class Operations
{
    private static int _runId = 0;

    public static void ExecuteSimultaneously(Action action1, Action action2)
    {
        Action slightlyEarlierStartingAction;
        Action slightlyLaterStartingAction;

        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _runId) % 2 == 0)
        {
            slightlyEarlierStartingAction = action1;
            slightlyLaterStartingAction = action2;
        }
        else
        {
            slightlyEarlierStartingAction = action2;
            slightlyLaterStartingAction = action1;
        }

        int sync = 0;

        var taskA = new Task(() =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref sync);
            while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sync, 3, 2) != 2) ;

            slightlyLaterStartingAction();
        });

        var taskB = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sync, 2, 1) != 1) ;

            slightlyEarlierStartingAction();
        });

        taskA.Start();
        taskB.Start();

        Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB);
    }
}
```

Synchronization precision is about **130 ns** in this implementation and probability of each action to win the race is very close to 50%.

I found a way to fine-tune synchronization precision even a bit further by scheduling those tasks on high-priority foreground thread, but I think it is an overkill for me. Still, sharing if somebody finds it useful:

```
public class PriorityScheduler : TaskScheduler
{
    public static PriorityScheduler Highest = new PriorityScheduler(ThreadPriority.Highest);
    //public static PriorityScheduler AboveNormal = new PriorityScheduler(ThreadPriority.AboveNormal);
    //public static PriorityScheduler BelowNormal = new PriorityScheduler(ThreadPriority.BelowNormal);
    //public static PriorityScheduler Lowest = new PriorityScheduler(ThreadPriority.Lowest);

    private BlockingCollection<Task> _tasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();
    private Thread[] _threads;
    private ThreadPriority _priority;
    private readonly int _maximumConcurrencyLevel = 2;//Math.Max(1, Environment.ProcessorCount);

    public PriorityScheduler(ThreadPriority priority)
    {
        _priority = priority;
    }

    public override int MaximumConcurrencyLevel
    {
        get { return _maximumConcurrencyLevel; }
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Task> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        return _tasks;
    }

    protected override void QueueTask(Task task)
    {
        _tasks.Add(task);

        if (_threads == null)
        {
            _threads = new Thread[_maximumConcurrencyLevel];
            for (int i = 0; i < _threads.Length; i++)
            {
                int local = i;
                _threads[i] = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    foreach (Task t in _tasks.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                        base.TryExecuteTask(t);
                });
                _threads[i].Name = string.Format("PriorityScheduler: ", i);
                _threads[i].Priority = _priority;
                _threads[i].IsBackground = false;
                _threads[i].Start();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override bool TryExecuteTaskInline(Task task, bool taskWasPreviouslyQueued)
    {
        return false; // we might not want to execute task that should schedule as high or low priority inline
    }
}

public class Operations
{
    private static int _runId = 0;

    public static void ExecuteSimultaneously(Action action1, Action action2)
    {
        Action slightlyEarlierStartingAction;
        Action slightlyLaterStartingAction;

        if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _runId) % 2 == 0)
        {
            slightlyEarlierStartingAction = action1;
            slightlyLaterStartingAction = action2;
        }
        else
        {
            slightlyEarlierStartingAction = action2;
            slightlyLaterStartingAction = action1;
        }

        int sync = 0;
        var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();

        var taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Interlocked.Increment(ref sync);
            while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sync, 3, 2) != 2) ;

            slightlyLaterStartingAction();
        }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.None, PriorityScheduler.Highest);

        var taskB = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref sync, 2, 1) != 1) ;

            slightlyEarlierStartingAction();
        }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.None, PriorityScheduler.Highest);

        Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB);
    }
}
```

This allowed me optimizing sync precision to **~100 ns**:

```
First  win count: 4992559, percentage: 49,92559
Second win count: 5007441, percentage: 50,07441
Avg sync diff: 98ns
```

**WARNING:** Using highest-priority thread may limit your computer responsiveness, especially when you don't have free processor cores.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ManualResetEvent.

Something like:

```
var waitEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);


var task1 = new Task(() =>
{
    waitEvent.WaitOne();
    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref x, 1, 0);
    time1 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
});
var task2 = new Task(() =>
{
    waitEvent.WaitOne();
    Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref x, 2, 0);
    time2 = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
});
task1.Start();
task2.Start();

// a startup delay? so the thread can be queued/start executing
// but still then, you're not aware how busy the threadpool is.
Thread.Sleep(1000);

waitEvent.Set();

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
```

Comment: This has exactly the same problems that starting two tasks at the same time does.  Each one can be woken up whenever the OS feels like it, and they could be radically far apart from each other in time (or not, we have no idea, which is the same that can be said of starting two tasks at the same time).

Comment: I think this comes as close as it can get, if it comes to simultaneously. This will lose the threadstartup/queing of the threadpool..

Comment: Your code gives average sync time difference ~1150 ns, which is comparable to just starting tasks one by one, as @Servy predicred.

Comment: Isn't that the time `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref x, 2, 0);` needs to execute?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, no. With interlock constructs I was able to get 130ns syncronization precision which is almost 10 times more precise then ManualResetEvent approach.